# Open cart failed to load english language

Tags: php, opencart

I am new to open cart. I have uploaded a store from local to live but it says the following error

> Notice: Error: Could not load language english! in /home7/neotjans/public_html/EBook/system/library/language.php on line 39

I have checked and uploaded the `english.php` file to `catalog/language/english` as it was mentioned in another tutorial but the error is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also the same problem. You are just missing the language file in `catalog/language/english/english.php`. Grab it from the default file and upload it back. It will solve the problem.

If this doesn't work for you then follow the second method here

1. Copy web_payment_software.php `file from admin\language\english\payment`
2. Paste to your language folder. `Sample: admin\language\vietnamese\payment`

Note: `web_payment_software.php` in folder `"admin\language\english\payment"`of OpenCart 1.5.1.3 version. Download full package to copy it!

Comment: read my question. I have mentioned there that I have uploaded that english.php file on this location

Comment: it was a path issue. Solved for now but still confused between the paths of localhost and live server :)